# Date format for : 17-Oct-13

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, date, datetime

Is there a predetermined format for a date as in: 17-Oct-13 ?

I cant seem to find a format like this? Sure I can just interpret it manually from the different date parts, but a format would be cool.

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) does not show such a format for date.

Comment: dd-MMM-yy is the thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format for that would be `dd-MMM-yy`. Custom date/time formatting is well  [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)...

Answer (score 4):

try `yourDateTimeVariable.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");`

Comment: Thanks, James was first tho.

Answer (score 2):

Just try like this (dd-MMM-yy) is the hing you are looking for.

You can test it like this.

```
String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Comment: Sure but i commented on that time, so answer was late

Comment: @LouisvanTonder see 5 min for his answer and my comment

Comment: Nope. 6 for him now, 7 for you... just missed it bud :-)

Comment: @LouisvanTonder Yup, next time i will be faster :P